Pronoun before and after compound verb
At 7:29 in this video, the following sentence is given:

Buenas días, me gustaría unirme a este gimnasio?

The compound verb is gustaría unir, and due to ending with an infinitive, the object pronoun can come at the end. However, it could alternatively be placed at the beginning, since it is a compound verb. In this case, the object pronoun is placed at both places.
I assume this is correct, but I wonder why/how this can be done. Isn't there only one set of pronouns for a verb, compound or not? And of course, one can have two object pronouns (for the DO and IO respectively), but that would mean that the speaker is the DO and IO, which I can't see here. They are the object of gustar, and they are the reflexive object of unir, but they are not the indirect object (right?). If anything is the indirect object, it would be the gym, but perhaps the a is serving a different role. If  the gym was indeed the IO then its IO pronoun would be mandatory.
So, what's what with this sentence? How does it work, and how could I replicate this kind of sentential structure correctly and incorrectly in the future?

In the sentence:

Me gustaría unirme a este gimnasio

the subject is the infinitival "unirme a este gimnasio" (within which "a este gimnasio" is a complement for the verb "unirme" -- compare with "inscribirme en este gimnasio", where "en este gimnasio" is more clearly an adverbial of place).
The first "me" is an indirect object, indicating who joining this gym would appeal to. The second "me" is required because "unirse" is used as a reflexive verb, meaning "becoming a member of".
We have two "me" because in the first and second person the indirect object (IO) and the reflexive pronouns are the same:

Me gustaría unirme a este gimnasio.
Nos gustaría unirnos a este gimnasio.
Te gustaría unirte a este gimnasio.
Os gustaría uniros a este gimnasio (peninsular Spanish)

In the third person, we find "le" and "les" for the IO and "se" as a reflexive mark:

Le gustaría unirse a este gimnasio.
Les gustaría unirse a este gimnasio.

We will find two such pronouns whenever we combine the so-called "psychological" verbs (verbs of emotion) with reflexive or quasi-reflexive (i.e. pronominal) verbs. The pronoun in the second part (which, I insist, is the grammatical subject of the sentence) can also be a direct or indirect object for the infinitive if the second verb is not pronominal (below I used rather literal translations for you to see that the infinitival is the subject):

Me interesa inscribirme en este gimnasio. (IO + reflexive/quasi-reflexive) (Signing up for this gym interests me)
Me divierte enfrentarme a un ignorante que se cree sabihondo. (IO + reflexive/quasi-reflexive) (Facing a know-it-all ignorant amuses me)
Le fastidia decirle la verdad. (IO + IO) (Telling him/her the truth upsets/annoys him/her)
Te sorprende verla tan joven (IO + DO) (Seeing her so young surprises you)

Note: Under 35.5l here you can find a rather complete list of the so-called psychological verbs that will follow this pattern.

I didn't have time to read through this properly until now, but I am glad I did. Great answer!

It's not a duplication. Both pronouns carry different information.
Consider the following:

Me gustaría uniros a este gimnasio = I'd like you to join this gym.

Also, without the second pronoun, the meaning changes completely:

Me gustaría unir este gimnasio (con el restaurante) = I'd like to join/attach/connect this gym (to the restaurant)



The compound verb is gustaría unir

Eso no existe. Uno de los dos hace el rol de verbo sintáctico y el otro no. Para analizar la oración deberíamos subdividirla en varios análisis simples y aplicar el principio de superposición finalmente.
Antes que nada, el verbo unir es pronominal en este caso porque quien une es el mismo que queda unido. Más precisamente, el ‘verbo’ presente sería unirse. Lo de las comillas vino porque lo que tenemos es una perífrasis verbal. Básicamente, como unirse es el segundo ‘verbo’ presente, es el que viene a jugar el rol de otra cosa que no sea el verbo sintáctico. El verbo sintáctico de la oración, por lo tanto, es gustar.
Ahora bien, primero supongamos que eligiéramos otro verbo más fácil de tratar como querer. En ese caso, sí tendríamos dos opciones:

Quiero unirme a este gimnasio.
Me quiero unir a este gimnasio.

Donde el sujeto está implícito, el verbo es quiero, unirme es el objeto directo y ‘este gimnasio’ es el complemento circunstancial. La libertad de poder mover el clítico antes o después es parte de las reglas para clíticos en perífrasis verbales.
Entonces, por qué gustar necesita el clítico antes y después obligatoriamente? En realidad la estructura cambia completamente porque en estos casos el verbo gustar indica que es la persona la afectada y el objeto el que afecta. Dicho de otro modo, ahora unirme a este gimnasio se convierte en el sujeto y quien lo dice en el objeto sintáctico. Para entenderlo mejor, una posibilidad es cambiar el final de la frase por otra cosa:

Me gusta unir mundos diferentes.

De donde deducimos que esa supuesta ‘duplicación’ del clítico no es ni ahí obligatoria con gustar, sino más bien una casualidad (por supuesto que es también una necesidad en tu oración) del ejemplo que trajiste .
Por fin, ponemos todo en orden con las conclusiones que sacamos.

‘(A mí) Me’: objeto indirecto +
‘gustaría’: verbo +
‘unirme a este gimnasio’: sujeto =


= tu ejemplo

En cuanto a consejos para el futuro, no mucho más que aclarar salvo que:

gustar suele requerir el objeto indirecto antes (que se camufla como sujeto para el que no esté atento). Hay casos en los que no lo lleva y la estructura vuelve a ser la típica (la persona el sujeto) pero es muy raro, por ejemplo en frases como ‘yo gusto (estoy enamorado) de X’ y cosas por el estilo pero en la gran mayoría de los casos lo requiere.
Cuando lo requiera, es opcional duplicarlo explícitamente con ‘a mí’ (‘a él’, ‘a ella’, etc.). O sea: ‘A mí + me gusta’. Como dato de color, hay una variante que es con el pronombre indirecto pospuesto pero está muy pasada de moda (cf. por ejemplo ‘gústame andar los caminos cazando madreñas tras de las mujeres’ en Cuélebre de Víctor Manuel).
No conozco un repertorio con la lista de verbos que requieran esta estructura atípica. El DLE no da mucha información con gustar y menciona las acepciones que se usan sin el OI. En cualquier caso, seguro que me gusta y los sinónimos como me encanta, me complace, me atrae, me llama, etc. todos van con esa estructura. Te queda de tarea completar la lista.

